# javascript string break meta tag in express handlebars

Tags: javascript, string, express, handlebars.js

iam using express with handlebars as template engine to render meta tag dynamically.
this is my script

```
var express = require("express");
var prerender = require("prerender-node");
var app = module.exports = express();
var handlebars = require("express-handlebars");

app.engine("handlebars", handlebars({defaultLayout: "main"}));
app.set("view engine", "handlebars");

app.use(prerender.set("prerenderToken", "qi2e5B985PptQE8aF0dt"));
app.use(express.static("./"));
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    // res.sendFile("./index.html");
    res.render("home", {
        title: "PLUNQ",
        metaKeyword: "temukan dan ciptakan perjalananmu sendiri, create trip, create diary, follow trip, hidden places, aplikasi untuk traveller",
        metaDescription: "Temukan dan ciptakan perjalananmu disini, Situs yang menyediakan rujukan tempat menarik, event, penginapan serta produk lokal",
        ogTitle: "Plunq | Temukan dan ciptakan perjalananmu disini",
        ogUrl: "https://plunq.id/",
        ogDescription: "Temukan dan ciptakan perjalananmu disini, Situs yang menyediakan rujukan tempat menarik, event, penginapan serta produk lokal",
        ogImage: "https://plunq.id/images/og-image.jpg",
    });
});

app.listen(1234);
```

and this is my handlebars

```
    <title>{{title}}</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content={{metaKeyword}}>
    <meta name="description" content={{metaDescription}}>
    <!-- og meta start here -->
    <link rel="canonical" href={{ogUrl}}/>
    <meta property="og:title" content={{ogTitle}}/>
    <meta property="og:url" content={{ogUrl}}/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
    <meta property="og:description" content={{ogDescription}}/>
    <meta property="og:image" content={{ogImage}}/>
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="921046191363161"/>
```

iam gonna passing the og and meta property to my template. the value is successfully passing to the template but it breaks my meta tag when i see in the browser, so it will displaying like this.
[image]

how to fix that :(

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap content in quotes(`"`)

```
<meta name="keywords" content="{{metaKeyword}}">
```

Its been part  [HTML 4.0 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2)

> all attribute values be delimited using either double quotation marks (ASCII decimal 34) or single quotation marks (ASCII decimal 39). Single quote marks can be included within the attribute value when the value is delimited by double quote marks, and vice versa.